# Ошибка при загрузки JSON

Tags: golang

Загружаю JSON со стороннего сервера. Код:

```
client := new(http.Client)
resp, _ , _ := client.Get(url)
message := make([]byte, 1000)
resp.Body.Read(message)
err := json.Unmarshal(message, &MyStruct)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.String())
}
return &MyStruct, err
```

Из `Unmarshal` все время выпадает след. ошибка:

> invalid character 'x00' after top-level value

В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убедитесь, что Ваш буффер ровно того размера, сколько занимает JSON-строка. Те, строка не только должна вместится в Ваш буффер, но и быть не больше этого буффера.

```
message := make([]byte, 1000)
l, _ := resp.Body.Read(message)
message = message[:l]
```

Если Ваше JSON-сообщение поместится в буффер, Вы его распарсите.

**UPD**

Лучшим способом будет использование библиотечной ф-и `ReadAll` из пакета `io/ioutil`

```
message, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(string(message)), &someStruct)
```

Comment: Вместо `json.Unmarshal([]byte(string(message)), &someStruct)` достаточно `json.Unmarshal(message, &someStruct)`

Answer (score 0):

Я, конечно, не силен в go, но может там русские буквы или другой не проэкранированный символ UTF?

Еще вариант, что длинны отведенной вами под message могло не хватить в результате Unmarshal не смог разобрать JSON, так как он обрезался и имеет некорректный формат.

Ну и третье предположение,  веб-сервер вам вообще ничего не прислал.

Comment: Нет. Там отправляется ansii. А в го, вроде, по-умолчанию юникод строки.